# Paragraph is copying attributes of the list above it

Tags: html, styles, paragraph

The text in my paragraph below my unordered list is inheriting the attributes of the last item on the list above it for some reason. Including the fact that it's a link and the color of text itself. It was white originally on the last item of the list but I changed it to pink for visibility sake. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to make the text in the paragraph a different color but that did nothing.

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none;margin: 0;padding: 0; color:color:#ff00ff; background-color:darkblue">
  <li style=display:inline;> <a href="" style="color:white"> Home </li>
 <li style=display:inline;> <a href="" style="color:white"> Education </li>
 <li style=display:inline;> <a href="" style="color:white"> Work Experience </li>
 <li style=display:inline;> <a href="" style="color:pink"> Hobbies </li>
 </ul>

<article>
 <p> BLANK is a student at BLANK <br> He is currently enrolled in the Computer Information Systems <br> program at the school. He is expected to graduate in 2019. </p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close youre `<a>` tag

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none;margin: 0;padding: 0; color:color:#ff00ff; background-color:darkblue;">
  <li style=display:inline;> <a href="" style="color:white;"> Home</a> </li>
  <li style=display:inline;> <a href="" style="color:white;"> Education</a> </li>
  <li style=display:inline;> <a href="" style="color:white;"> Work Experience</a> </li>
  <li style=display:inline;> <a href="" style="color:pink;"> Hobbies</a> </li>
</ul>

<article>
  <p> BLANK is a student at BLANK <br> He is currently enrolled in the Computer Information Systems <br> program at the school. He is expected to graduate in 2019. </p>
</article>
```

Comment: I did not even think of that, so simple. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
  <ul style="list-style-type: none;margin: 0;padding: 0; color:color:#ff00ff; background-color:darkblue">
    <li style="display:inline"> <a href="" style="color:white"> Home</a> </li>
    <li style="display:inline"> <a href="" style="color:white"> Education</a> </li>
    <li style="display:inline"> <a href="" style="color:white"> Work Experience</a> </li>
    <li style="display:inline"> <a href="" style="color:pink"> Hobbies</a> </li>
  </ul>


  <article>
    <p> BLANK is a student at BLANK <br> He is currently enrolled in the Computer Information Systems <br> program at the school. He is expected to graduate in 2019. </p>
  </article>

</body>
```

You were missing some quotes on your style attributes and the main culprit was that you had no closing tags for the `<a>` tags